# How can I implement Squats counter in Android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am interested in how can I realize applications such as [Runtastic Pull Ups](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.runtastic.android.pullup.pro) in Android, but for squats counting.

I know, i need to use accelerometer for it. But I can't understand how to implement device up-down counting. What sensors should I use, accelerometer or gravity? Could anyone give me some tips about it.

Thanks.

Comment: start by collecting data: log values of all sensors you think may be relevant when you do your squats, then see which one seems more likely to give you a clear reading.

Answer (score 1):

Make several squats with accelerometer turned on. Then visualize/analyze the data - you will clear patterns as it will look like: nothing - sudden move - nothing - sudden move - nothing. It is one squat. I do some jumps with accelerometer to check my landings and patterns are there.

You can add gyroscope too, depending where you put accelerometer. For me, the best place would be upper leg or chest.

Comment: Can share if you have any code sample link or any other material related to this